# AWS s3 cross-account website AccessDenied

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have 2 AWS accounts, accountA and accountB.

I'm sending some static website file from accountA to accountB using:

```
aws s3 cp s3:BucketA s3://BucketB --recursive --acl bucket-owner-full-control
```

Everything works fine until I try to access the website, when I get an `AccessDenied` error.

If the `acl` doesn't work, what should I do?

Ps. My bucket is already configured to be used as a website and, if I upload the files from the account itself, I can perfectly access the website.

Comment: There is already a policy to make the objects public. `{"Effect": "Allow", "Principal": "*", "Action": "s3:GetObject","Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::BucketB/*"}`. Or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: The problem is going to be that accountB does not own the objects so the bucket policy doesn't apply. Believe that the accountA copier will have to apply the public-read ACL while copying, or the accountB bucket owner will have to take ownership of the objects after copying (by copying each object over itself, possibly with some minor modification such as metadata).

Comment: You need to pass acl "public read" otherwise only the bucket owner account would have access , since you're still the owner of the object, it'll be accessible public unless the bucket owner account recopy the object and become the owner and enable public access or bucket policy for *.

Comment: To which account is the `aws s3 cp` command being sent? Is it using credentials from Account-A or Account-B?

Comment: I see. Setting the `public-read` worked like a charm. Should I (could I) then set the acl both to `public-read` and `bucket-owner-full-control`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that accountB does not own the objects so the bucket policy doesn't apply to those objects. There are two ways to resolve this:

1. The accountA copier will have to apply the public-read ACL *while* copying.
2. The accountB bucket owner will have to take ownership of the objects *after* copying (by copying each object over itself, possibly with some minor modification such as metadata).

The simplest solution is #1 in which case I would recommend that you apply *both* `public-read` and `bucket-owner-full-control` ACLs at the time you copy the files.

Comment: I didn't know I could set both ACLs. Thank you!